# AVLTree copy causing segmentation fault c++

Tags: c++

I have a TreeAVL class that until that point worked perfectly fine as is working my Node class.

I'm trying to implement a copy constructor for AVLTree and for this reason I'm trying to use an internal function called `copy` .

My test cause a segmentation fault inside the `copy`  function when it tries to attribute a value to a node.

Here is the code and I point where is the error:

```
template <class T>
TreeAVL<T>::TreeAVL(const TreeAVL<T> &other)
    : root(nullptr)
{
    copy(other.root, root);
}

template <class T>
void TreeAVL<T>::copy(const Node *root, Node *&node) const
{
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        // Left node
        Node *newNodeLeft = new Node(root->left->value);
        // This is where the segmentation fault happen
        node->left = newNodeLeft;
        copy(root->left, node->left);
        // Right node
        Node *newNodeRight = new Node(root->right->value);
        node->right = newNodeRight;
        copy(root->right, node->right);
    }
}

void main() {
TreeAVL<int> a1;
   a1.insert(1);
   a1.insert(2);
   a1.insert(3);
   a1.insert(4);
   a1.insert(5);
   TreeAVL<int> a2(a1);
}
```

I can provide more code if needed. Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Let's see the `insert` function.  A quick and dirty way of creating the copy constructor is to repeatedly call `this->insert(data)` while traversing the tree to be copied, picking up the data for each node.  In other words, the tree that will be copied would mimic `insert(1); insert(2); insert(3); insert(4); insert(5);` for `this`.  Do you have a traversal function?  If you did it this way, there would be no calls to `new Node`, rebalancing, etc., as the `insert()` function would take care of all of those details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will try to use the insert function, it's a pretty big function but I know it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if `root->left` is null before dereferencing the pointer. Same applies to `root->right`.

```
template <class T>
void TreeAVL<T>::copy(const Node *root, Node *&node) const
{
    if (root != nullptr)
    {
        if (root->left != nullptr) { // Left node
            Node *newNodeLeft = new Node(root->left->value);
            // This is where the segmentation fault happen
            node->left = newNodeLeft;
            copy(root->left, node->left);
        }

        if (root->right != nullptr) { // Right node
            Node *newNodeRight = new Node(root->right->value);
            node->right = newNodeRight;
            copy(root->right, node->right);
        }
    }
}
```